# pymongo - use find with multiple conditions

Tags: python, mongodb, nested, pymongo

I want to find the specific record from MongoDB.The documentation is stored like that:

```
{
    "_id": "",
    "obj": [{
        "language": "en",
        "name": "david",
        "value":7000,
        "created_at": "Wed, 12 Sep 2018 15:25:48 +0000"
    }.....]

}
```

The user will give the input such as name and value and then it will return the matched record with those input value. If I try to do like:

```
def findrecord(collection,name,value):
    collection_query = {"obj.name":name,"obj.value" : value}
    record = collection.find(collection_query)
```

It will return all the records even some records are not matching.

Comment: I can see error in `"name": david,` as the value is stored not as string. Fixing that everything works fine.

Comment: @SmashGuy Actually it was a typo...

Comment: I have reproduced the same environment and everything seems fine. Can you give me a test case?